# Skip every second line in a txt file in Pascal

Tags: pascal

This is my code (don't mind the German variable names):

```
  IF Frage = 1 THEN
  BEGIN

        Reset(Textdatei);
        Writeln;
        i := 0;

        WHILE NOT EoF(Textdatei) DO
        BEGIN
              Inc(i);
              Readln(Textdatei,Dateiname);

              // NUMMER
              IF i < 10 THEN
              BEGIN
                    Temp := Copy(Dateiname,2,1);  // Speichert position als Str
                    posTemp := StrToInt(Temp);    // position wird als Int gespeichert
                    pos0 := posTemp;

              END;

              IF (i < 100) AND (i > 9) THEN
              BEGIN
                    Temp := Copy(Dateiname,2,2);
                    posTemp := StrToInt(Temp);
                    pos0 := posTemp;

              END;

              IF (i >= 100) THEN
              BEGIN
                    Temp := Copy(Dateiname,2,3);
                    posTemp := StrToInt(Temp);
                    pos0 := posTemp;

              END;

              // NAME
              posTemp := pos(' ',Dateiname);
              posTemp2:= pos('.',Dateiname);
              UnknownLength := (posTemp2-1) - posTemp;
              Temp := Copy(Dateiname,posTemp+1,UnknownLength);
              Name := Temp;

              // KG
              posTemp := pos('// ',Dateiname);
              posTemp2:= pos('kg',Dateiname);
              posTemp := posTemp + 2;
              UnknownLength :=  (posTemp2-1) - posTemp;
              Temp := Copy(Dateiname,posTemp,UnknownLength);
              posTemp := StrToInt(Temp);
              KG := posTemp;

              //Liste beschreiben
              Liste := AddElement(Name, pos0, KG, Liste);



        END;

  END;

  ClrScr;
  Writeln('Laden erfolgreich!');
  Readkey;
  Submenu();
```

So, this code does not work right, because the txt file that I load contains empty lines. To be more precise: every SECOND line in the txt is empty. That means, that I have to skip every empty line when filling my chained list with the elements from the txt.

- How can I tell the compiler to skip every 2 / empty line ?
- How can I tell my compiler to only read a certain line ?

If you answer either of my questions I can finally finish my little program.

---

The inside of my txt looks exactly like this:

```
#1: Bisasam. // 11 kg 

#2: Bisaknosp. // 22 kg

#3: Bisaflor. // 33 kg
```

So as you can see, every second line is blank and when it tries to load a blank line into my list it crashes.

Comment: Hello:) Yeah, I can do that, but then I need to tell the compiler still to just ignore a blank line and I just dont know the syntax for skip line or count the lines or whatever .. sorry im a beginner :/ couldnt find anyhing on google either...

Comment: Thanks but somehow it doesnt work. It always crashes on this line when attempting to go through the loop a second time: posTemp := StrToInt(Temp);   ---- but maybe the problem is not the empty line maybe its something else cause the mod testing shouldve totally worked... yet it still crashes right there..: :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an extra `Readln` to skip the blank line, so your code becomes:

```
      ...

      WHILE NOT EoF(Textdatei) DO
        BEGIN
          Inc(i);

          // *** read non-empty line containing data ***
          Readln(Textdatei,Dateiname);

          ...

          //Liste beschreiben
          Liste := AddElement(Name, pos0, KG, Liste);

          // *** skip empty line ***
          Readln(Textdatei);

        END;

      ...
```

Note that this assumes that the non-empty lines are the odd lines in the file, i.e. the first line is non-empty, the second line is empty, etc. If it's the other way round then move the `Readln(Textdatei);` to the start of the `WHILE` loop instead of the end.

Comment: Thank you too, but it doenst work. When I try that, all it does is to let me just type something into the compiler and then it crashes afterwards. Testing the Mod thing does not work either unfortunately, and i dont know why :( Im so close to finishing my first "big" project if i get the while loop the skip every empty or every odd or every second line in the txt file ...

Comment: @user7285912: my bad -  I missed out the file descriptor - sorry - try the fixed version...

Comment: Interesting.. Now what it does is, it lets me press enter three more times until it crashes... Did i maybe miss something else? :s Any chance i could send you the whole code ? xD

Comment: The only change is the addition of that line - you may have other bugs in your code that you need to work on. BTW, if you haven't learned to use a debugger yet then now would be a good time to start - it will let you step through the code and see what is happening to your variables as the code executes.

Comment: OH IT WORKS! ... I think what cuased my problems was, that i left the file open while reading from it. So maybe my pc was unable to find eof then.. I dont know BUT THANKS!

Comment: O, i have one last question: Now that i do that, I have to press enter for as many times as i have rows in my txt ... Would u have an idea what the cause of that is? :)

Comment: I can't see any reason for that in the code you have shown - you'll need to do some further debugging...